# Unable to Compile Applications

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

No matter which project I choose, I am getting the same error when I go to run the app in the simulator (iPhone).  I am using the latest iPhone SDK and Titanium SDK (though I also had problems before that).

```
[INFO] Compiling JavaScript...one moment
[INFO] No JavaScript errors detected.
[INFO] One moment, building ...
[INFO] Titanium SDK version: 1.6.1
[INFO] iPhone Device family: iphone
[INFO] iPhone SDK version: 4.3
[INFO] iPhone simulated device: iphone
[INFO] Performing full rebuild. This will take a little bit. Hold tight...
[INFO] Skipping JS compile, running from simulator
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.1/iphone/builder.py", line 1091, in main
execute_xcode("iphonesimulator%s" % link_version,["GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=__LOG__ID__=%s DEPLOYTYPE=development TI_DEVELOPMENT=1 DEBUG=1 TI_VERSION=%s" % (log_id,sdk_version)],False)
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.1/iphone/builder.py", line 1012, in execute_xcode
output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/1.6.1/iphone/run.py", line 39, in run
sys.exit(rc)
SystemExit: 65
```

Comment: i guess you already cleaned your build/iphone folder before compiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to try, if you haven't tried them yet:

1. Create a new project.  Just using the default generated code and none of your own code or code imported from elsewhere, try to run it in the emulator.  Does it work?  If so, copy everything except the build directory from a project that doesn't work into your new project.  Does it work now?  This is what I (and, judging from Internet forums, a lot of other people) needed to do to get the Kitchen Sink app to run, for example.
2. The error above is for the iPhone.  What happens if you install the Android SDK and try compiling as an Android app?  This is not really a solution, but it would be useful information for someone trying to help you.

Not exactly a slam-dunk here's-how-to-fix-it answer, but hopefully something that gets you on the right track (or if it's stuff you already tried, edit your post to mention that!).